# C# BackgroundWorker - better to save results to a file itself or use ProgressChanged?

Tags: c#, multithreading

I am new to multi-threaded programming. In my C# project, I have a class which runs a long job; this class has a BackgroundWorker object as one of its properties.  The user interface instantiates my class, then calls RunWorkerAsync on the BackgroundWorker.

Every so often, my class saves its results to a file; the results are a complex object (several matrices, strings etc). Then it reports its progress via the ProgressChanged event.  My simple GUI then picks up on the ProgressChanged and puts the percentage progress on a label on the form.

I have thought of an alternative which is easy to implement.  My class could pass the results back as part of the ProgressChanged event inside the ProgressChangedEventArgs.UserState.  Is this a good idea, or not?

Comment: `My class could pass the results back`. What are the results, Type/Size?

Comment: Grant Winney - maybe I didn't make it clear enough.  The saving to a file isn't done in order to report progress.  They are two separate things, which just happen to occur at the same time.

Comment: Ash Burlaczenko - I have edited the question.  The results are several matrices which are written to different files.

Comment: If it would make sense for the user to see partial results while the `BackgroundWorker` is still processing, then sure, pass them back on the `UserState.`  Don't do it if it doesn't make sense, or would confuse the user.

Answer (score 2):

Saving to a file is a potentially long-running operation. It should not run on the UI thread. Leave it on the `BackgroundWorker` or switch to async/await if you can.